# plotting the graph after calculation from the list in anaconda

Tags: python, plot

I have taken some data as list using `numpy.loadtxt`, which is just data of time and velocity. I can calculate the displacement at every second but the graph I am getting is weird in both x and y axes.

Here is the code:

```
## this program loads the values from velocities.txt file
# and calculates the displacement, but it can not plot the graph.

from numpy import loadtxt
from numpy import array

a=loadtxt("c:\\users\prism infotech\\documents\\python scripts\\velocities.txt")

k=100
disp1 =0.5*a[k,1]+0.5*a[k-1,1]
for k in range (1,99):
    disp1 +=0.5*a[k,1]+0.5*a[k-1,1]
    print "displacement at second",k,disp1
   # print a[:,0],disp


from pylab import plot,show
x=k
y=disp1
plot(x,y)
show()
```

[Image of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT144.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are plotting a single 2D point. (k = 98, last iteration of the above for loop, hence the plot centered around 98).

In case you would like to plot ***arrays*** disp1 vs k, you could do something like this:

```
## this program loads the values from velocities.txt file
# and calculates the displacement, but it can not plot the graph.

import numpy as np

a=np.loadtxt("c:\\users\prism infotech\\documents\\python scripts\\velocities.txt")

# initialize arrays k, disp1
# i also assume you have 100 elements in the array, so range(1, 101) 
# produces numbers 1 - 100
k = np.array(range(1, 101))

# produces a numpy array of zeros, of length 100
disp1 = np.zeros((100, ))

# now you do whatever you want with your arrays
# your code here

#plotting 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(k, disp1)
plt.show()
```